# I am writing a program for CS50x Pset 4 Recover in C. After I read the first block and then try to write it I receive a segmentation fault

Tags: recover

CS50X PSet 4 Recover

I read the first block of data and check whether it is the beginning of a jpeg file.  After determining the beginning of the jpeg I then try to write the first block which then causes a segmentation fault.

I have isolated the segmentation fault to writing the first 512 bytes to the output file.

Here is a relevant code sect

```
// FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
FILE* file = NULL;
file = malloc(514 * sizeof(char));
file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
printf("count zero = %d\n", count );

// Check if *file is NULL
if (!file)
{
    printf("count return = %d\n", count );
    return 1;
}

// initialize first_image = 1 for first image
// int first_image=0;

// Read block of 512  bytes
count = fread(bytes, sizeof(char), 512, file);
printf("count = %d\n", count );

while (count != 0)
{
    printf("count 52 = %d\n", count );

    // check if bytes are the jpg header 0xff 0xd8 0xff and oxe? (jpeg)
    if (*bytes[0] == 0xff && *bytes[1] == 0xd8 && *bytes[2] == 0xff && (*bytes[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    {
        printf("count 56= %d\n", count );

        if (n == 0)
        {
            // create filename
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", n );
            filename = malloc(9 * sizeof(char));
            // *filename = malloc(9 * sizeof(char));

            // open first file
            fileout = malloc(512 * sizeof(char));
            fileout = fopen(filename,"w");

            // write data to first file
            fwrite(&bytes, sizeof(char), count,
```

Comment: Where is *bytes* defined? Did you allocate enough memory for it?

Comment: did you ensure that *fileout* is valid handle?

Comment: Here is the definition for bytes and fileout in portions of the code I did not copy here        FILE *fileout=NULL;    unsigned char *bytes[513];  Are these incorrect?

Comment: Why this expression:  fileout = malloc(512 * sizeof(char));    is needed? You override this value just in the next line. Ensure also that after the line *fileout = fopen(filename,"w");* the *fileout* is still valid. the *fopen* could return NULL.

Comment: Are you sure that *sizeof(char)* on your platform returns 1? this is not obvious.

Comment: "unsigned char **bytes[513]*;" What did you want to achieve here? Array of pointers? Plain memory block should be allocated as unsigned char bytes[513] or unsigned char* bytes = malloc(513)